# commit eclipse to IBM DevOps

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-watson

I'm relatively new to IBM Bluemix. So i am running a Speech to Text java project at Eclipse, using instructions from this link: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/bluemix-watson-apis-quickstart-using-java-sdk/

The code is running fine at Eclipse, but if you see the 3rd last step at the instruction, they are connecting the eclipse code to DevOps using "Commit and Push". I tried doing that step and Pushed from eclipse. also i could see the pushed files at my Git section of DevOps Services. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xJWM.png)  But i do not know to proceed further. as in; how to trigger a new deployment process at DevOps Services. When I do build and Deploy, its deployed successfully but it does not show any result when I do Open Deployed app link. Can anyone please help and let me know what mistake i'm doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned, in the image you attached I can see the changes you committed from Eclipse to the repo, so the changes are available on the *master* branch.

Now if you want to manually trigger a deploy on Bluemix you can go to the *Build & Deploy* and then run the build stage. That will start the build+deploy phase and you should find the updated application running on Bluemix when the process is completed. The reason why you see the old version of the application may depend on a misconfiguration of the build stage, resulting in a .war file that doesn't contain the changes. I suggest you to check the stage settings (mainly the *Input* and *Jobs* sections of the stage configuration panel). Then you could check the *Last Execution Result* section to see the content of the packaged .war file (*Artifacts* section).

Finally, I suggest you to take a look at [this page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/d-bluemix-javadevops/index.html) to see how to integrate the pipeline in Eclipse.